# Removing text from a text file

Tags: python, sed

I have a text file that contains URLs that I need to make shortcuts from. The file has other information that I don't need. 
For example:
event number - xyz

```
More text here
And here

ALL https://.....

Atendees URLs 

1 -tab- https://.....
2 -tab- https://...
etc.
```

Right now I remove the extra text and empty lines and keep lines with only the URLs(plus the \n \t). I then with this code in python put the URLs into a list.

```
def fileOpen(self):

        self.skytap = []
        with open(self.file_1, 'r') as f:   
            for line in f:
                self.skytap.append(line.strip('\t\r\n'))
```

I would like to know if there is a way in Python to remove all text, numbering etc and keep the https://........ URLSs only in the order in which they are in the file and of course put them in the list so I can make the shortcuts(I have making of the shortcuts solved)
I've looked at some of the questions online and some people suggested sed as a better tool for this. Would that be the case.
I am new to programing and appreciate any insight given on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this with `sed` but the tool you are looking for is `grep`:

```
grep -o 'https\?://[^ ]\+' file.txt
```

It extracts the sequence `http` plus subsequent non-space characters.

Comment: Great! Thanks I am able to only keep the lines with https in it with grep like you said and echo it to a separate file. However I still have on each line a number and then a <tab> before the https. How do I remove those?

Comment: The line numbers can be caused by an alias in `.bashrc` or your `$GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable. Use `GREP_OPTIONS= /bin/grep -o` instead of just `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file in place using `fileinput.input` finding the lines with `https://` with `re`:

```
import  fileinput
import  re

r = re.compile(r"https://.*")
urls = []
for line in fileinput.input("match.txt",inplace=True):
     s = r.search(line)
     if s:
        print(line,end="")
        urls.append(s.group())
```

If you are using python 2 add a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your code.

If you want to remove the substring before the https in the file also replace `print(line,end="")` with `print(s.group(),end="")`

Or as @Jon kindly pointed out, import sys and use `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import  fileinput
import  re
import sys

r = re.compile(r"https://.*")
urls = []
for line in fileinput.input("match.txt",inplace=True):
     s = r.search(line)
     if s:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        urls.append(s.group())
```

Comment: Since `fileinput` "hijacks" stdout... to make it both 2.x and 3.x compatible `import sys` then `sys.stdout.write(line)` :)

Comment: @JonClements,  yep,added.

Comment: @JonClements At the moment I have to deal with Python and asking myself, why the hell did they do that python2, 3 decision.. Now the code gets even more complicated since many application cannot decide if they want to run with python2 or 3. It's as if I would need to code for PHP4 and 5. Unbelivable! (for me)

Comment: @hek2mgl it's already a regret of the BDFL it was ever a statement - might have just seemed a good idea when the language was younger? :p Oh well...

Comment: I really *want* to love Python, but to do so is sometimes still hard for me. Give me more time ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help you: How about you search for this regex: `https?://[A-Za-z0-9-._~:/?#[\]@!$&\',*+,;=]*`
It searches for all valid URL characters

In fact, here's a program which should do the job (Untested):

```
import re

string="""
More text here
And here

ALL https://.....

Atendees URLs 

1 -tab- https://.....
2 -tab- https://...
etc.
"""

links = re.compile(r'https?://[A-Za-z0-9-._~:/?#[\]@!$&\',*+,;=]*').findall(string)
```